# Why isn't my Python script running the code it's meant to when Space = 5?

Tags: python

Why isn't my Python script running the code it's meant to when Space = 5?

I wanted it to run this code when Space gets to 5:

```
  print ("Ladder!")
  Space = 16
  print ("You're not on space " + str(Space) + "!")
```

But it doesn't, and just goes onto the next turn.

The full code is:

```
import time
Space = 0
Turn = 0

while Space < 100:
  Turn = Turn + 1
  print ("Turn " + str(Turn) + ":\n")
  DiceRoll = random.randint(1,6)
  print ("Dice Roll Number: " + str (DiceRoll))
  Space = Space + DiceRoll
  print ("Space: " + str(Space))
  print ("\n")
  time.sleep (2)

if (Space) > 99:
  print ("You win!")

if (Space) == 5:
  print ("Ladder!")
  Space = 16
  print ("You're now on space " + str(Space) + "!")
```

Comment: Because your if statement is outside and after the loop where you at to space until it's at least 100. So by the time the if statement is run, space never has a chance to be 5

Comment: Your `if` statements are not inside your `while` loop, space is incremented all way to 99, the loop exists, and only then are your `if` statements evaluated.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you expect to happen and what goes wrong? You start with `Space = 0` and then enter to the `while Sapce < 100`. So when you finish the loop and reach the `if` condition, `Space` wcan't be equal to `5`

Comment: @xibalba1 thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions won't apply until after you exit the while loop. If you want you conditions to be checked want turn you need to indent them so that they are within the while loop.